# SSIS package can't access directory when run on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am running a SSIS package which includes a script to check if a file exists.

When I run this in Visual Studio under my Windows credentials, it works fine and can find the file within the directory and has access.

When I deploy the package on to SQL Server and run it (still under my windows credentials, I even printed them in a log message within the script), it doesn't have access to the directory.

Note: I am not running this within an agent job, I am directly running it under the integration service package within SQL Server Management Studio.

Edit: The database is held on a remote server, which when I log into that server and use management studio there it all works fine. If I connect to the remote server as me on my machine however it doesn't

Does anyone know why?

Comment: It is a remote machine, I have placed messages within the package however that say it is running as me, Environment.UserName comes out as me whether I run it on the remote machine (Sql server management studio) or on my machine in visual studio

Comment: What task are you using to check for the file existence (script task or a bat file)? How are you checking for file existence?

Comment: It sounds like a kerberos double hop problem. Please post exact error for accessing the file.

Comment: Just using a C# script, I'm using File.Exists firstly to check if it exists then if it doesn't I check permissions on the directory. Works fine on my machine in VS but exception on SQL management studio

Comment: I think you need to check which account run SQL Server Agent in Service, and use that give folder access to that account, based on my experience, I will prefer to use a individual account to run SQL Server Agent,.

Comment: I'm not using the agent I'm running it directly from the package, I even print the user in C# and it's the same user

Answer (score 0):

Try giving read/write permissions to the SQL Database Engine Service account `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$<Instance Name>` *(Where `<Instance Name>` should be replaced by the installed instance name)*:

- [Configure File System Permissions for Database Engine Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Suppose 2 computers have sql installed with the same instance name. Then, is NT SERVICE\InstanceName - is this account common to all computers in the network or is it unique per computer? I am trying to understand whether it is a local account or is it a shared network account?

Comment: @variable check this link: https://superuser.com/questions/884988/what-is-nt-authority-and-nt-service